# Как сравнивать строки в Java?

Tags: java, строки, сравнение, java-faq

В своей программе я использовал оператор `==` для сравнения строк. Но я наткнулся на баг, и при замене `==` на `equals` он пропал.​​​​​​​​​​

Следует избегать оператора `==`? Когда его можно использовать, а когда нет? В чём разница?

Comment: Добавил ещё один "канонический" ответ. На английском SO это самый популярный вопрос как цель для закрытия дубликатов. Преимущественно перевод и компиляция [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), плюс ещё по мелочи.

Comment: Школа на Хэшкоде :)

Comment: Извини, но ты сам себя спросил, и сам же себе ответил?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Да. См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @AndrewBystrov на SO это нормально, хотя я думал что "самоответ" синхронно с вопросом это не комильфо, но в правилах противопоказаний нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает оператор ==](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496080/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80)

Comment: @ReinRaus Это самодостаточный QA с более скучкованным объяснением для закрытия как дубликатов, а не статья. Он оптимизирован для новичков и прекрасно работает. Не надо объединять 10 вопросов в один с менее внятными объяснениями.

Comment: @Discord хз. Может я и не прав, но лучше сделать один "эталонный" ответ и вопрос и закрывать на него все остальные точно такие же вопросы. Если возникает желание добавить по теме, то улучшать "эталонный" ответ.

Comment: @ReinRaus "Эталонный" ответ по этой теме слишком обширен. Нельзя впихать все нюансы использования оператора равенства для всех типов в один ответ. Написанный недавно ответ — яркий тому пример. См. мои комментарии под ним.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Оператор `==` сравнивает ссылки.

Метод `equals` сравнивает значения.

Следовательно, если вы хотите сравнить строки на равенство, следует использовать `equals`.

Однако в некоторых случаях строки гарантированно представлены одним и тем же объектом благодаря [пулу строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BB_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) ([string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)). Эти случаи явно описаны в [спецификации языка Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

Оператор `==` используется для проверки, что две строки указывают на один и тот же объект.

```
// Эти строки имеют одно и тоже же значение
new String("test").equals("test") // --> true 

// ...но это разные объекты
new String("test") == "test" // --> false 

// ...эти строки тоже разные объекты
new String("test") == new String("test") // --> false 

// ...но эти строки указывают на один и тот же объект,
// потому что компилятор добавляет все литералы в пул.
"test" == "test" // --> true 

// Конкатенация литералов тоже происходит на стадии компиляции,
// поэтому они указывают на один объект
"test" == "te" + "st" // --> true

// но вызов substring() происходит во время выполнения,
// в результате получаются разные объекты.
"test" == "!test".substring(1) // --> false

// Строки из пула могут быть получены с помощью вызова intern().
"test" == "!test".substring(1).intern() // --> true
```

Надо отметить, что `==` заметно быстрее, чем `equals` (сравнение ссылки вместо вызова метода и посимвольного сравнения, если строки разной длины), поэтому, если вы работаете со строками из пула (или системного, или своего), замена `equals` на `==` может привести к заметному ускорению. Но это **случается очень редко**.

Остерегайтесь вызова `equals` на `null`! Оператор `==` прекрасно сравнивает строки, если одна или более из них равна `null`, но вызов метода `equals` на строке, равной `null`, приведёт к исключению.

Для сравнения строк, которые могут быть равны `null`, вы можете воспользоваться следующим методом:

```
public static boolean equals(String str1, String str2) {
    return str1 == null ? str2 == null : str1.equals(str2);
}
```

Он присутствует в некоторых сторонних библиотеках, например, в Apache Commons.

Если вы пользуетесь современными средами разработки, то они предупредят, если вы попытаетесь сравнить строки с помощью оператора `==`. Всегда обращайте внимание на подобные предупреждения.

Comment: Если это канонический ответ, может, расписать про interning?

Comment: @VladD По-моему, это отдельный вопрос. Для тех, кто интересуется, как сравнивать строки, детали работы с interning несколько рано рассказывать. :)

Comment: Может тогда вместо "Однако в некоторых случаях строки гарантированно представлены одним и тем же объектом" например "В некоторых случаях сравнение через == _может_ давать правильный результат (см. interning насчёт деталей), но надеяться на это нельзя, разве что вы отчётливо понимаете, что делаете."?

Comment: @VladD "Надеяться" — неудачное слово, когда есть формальная спецификация. Важные случаи описаны в примере, а тащить все детали из спеки в этот ответ было бы излишним. Если хотите написать про interning, можете создать отдельный QA, расписать критерии во всех подробностях, расписать случаи использования, достоинства, недостатки, подводные камни и т.п. Тогда из этого вопроса можно было бы сослаться. По-моему, это было бы оптимальным.

Comment: Ну мы же пишем неформальное объяснение? "Рассчитывать"?

Comment: Хм. Попробую написать про interning.

Comment: @VladD Я не хочу портить корректную формулировку: спека всё гарантирует, и загвоздка может быть только с неполным пониманием спеки. Можно *добавить* что-то в духе: "Если вы сомневаетесь и не знаете, каким методом воспользоваться, используйте `equals`. Не стоит просто полагаться на то, что в каком-то отдельном случае оператор `==` сработал."

Comment: Ну, или с тем, что документацию никто не читает :-\

Comment: Написал: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417843/10105

Comment: `Оператор == сравнивает ссылки.` а как же быть с примитивными типами?

Comment: @rjhdby Применение оператора `==` и метода `equals` указано применительно к классу `String`. Вообще этот оператор сравнивает значения, просто значением переменной типа "строка" является указатель на адрес в памяти, где располагаются данные. Для примитивных типов значением является собственно значение.

Comment: @Squidward я в курсе. Просто на этот вопрос была дана ссылка с другого вопроса (т.е. он используется в качестве этакой wiki) и хорошо бы объяснить разницу без привязки конкретно к String, потому как человека не знающего фраза `Метод equals сравнивает значения.` может надолго ввести в заблуждение с последующими вопросами типа "а почему не работает int a=0;a.equals(0);?". Ну да на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: @rjhdby Чтобы объяснить работу оператора равенства в общем случае, нужно объяснить разницу между value-типами и reference-типами, а там уже вытягивается организация памяти и прочее. Я не представляю, как сформулировать объяснение и доступно, и полноценно, и практично одновременно. Поэтому этот QA я рассматриваю как "инструкцию по сравнению строк для новичков" и подробности описываемых методов считаю выходящими за его рамки. Подробности описаны в других QA, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496080, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417843 и др.

Answer (score 6):

Если быть коротко, то `==` сравнивает ссылки на объект, если ссылки указывают на один и тот же объект, то это тру, иначе false, в случае с примитивными типами `==` сравнивает значения.

`equals ()` используется в `String` так, он берет и сравнивает посимвольно каждый `String`, но это только со `String`, если брать остальные объекты (Вы создали объекты `Яблоко` и `Груша`), при этом в этих классах не прописан метод `equals`,то оно как и `==` сравнивает ссылки на объект, если это один и тот же объект, то тру иначе false.

В `String` прописан метод `equals ()`, который сравнивает посимвольно, поэтому со `String` нужно юзать `equals ()`