# Не выполняется условие равенства текста

Tags: java, android, jsoup

```
final String prov = "Вход";
final String my_number1 = "Условие TRUE";
```

условие:

```
if (my_number == prov)System.out.println(my_number1);
```

Переменная `my_number` берет значения после парсинга. Я проверал, значения одинаковы.

Comment: Не сравнивайте строки через `==`. В Java оператор `==` проаеряет на равенство ссылки на объекты, а не сами объекты. Хотите сравнивать объекты - используйте метод equals: `my_number.equals(prov)`.

Comment: На этот вопрос существует канонический исчерпывающий ответ.: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java) -

Answer (score 6):

Строки в Java надо сравнивать через `equals`:

```
if (my_number.equals(prov))
    System.out.println(my_number1);
```

Если одна строка зашита константой в программе, а другая получена в процессе разбора файла, они в принципе не могут быть одним и тем же объектом, потому что константа интернирована, а распарсенная строка — нет.

Comment: а числовые значения можно сравнивать с помощью `==` ?

Comment: @Денис, примитивные (`int`, `long` и т. д.) — можно, объекты (`Integer`, `Long`) — нет.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!