# Удалить дубликаты из массива

Tags: java, массивы

Что неверно в коде? Почему не работает? Нужно удалить дубликаты из массива.

```
public class Dublicate {

    public String[] delDublicate(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer esult = new StringBuffer();
        int i=1;

        for (int j=0; j <args.length; j++) {
            result.append(args[i]);
            String res = result.toString();
            esult.append(args[j]);
            String re = esult.toString();
            if (res.equals(re)){
                if (args[j]!= args[i]) {
                    args[i] = " ";
                }
            }
        }

        return args;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String [] res={"Привет", "Привет", "задание", "выполнено", "верно", "задание"};
        Dublicate dub=new Dublicate();
        dub.delDublicate(res);
        System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(res));
    }
}
```

Comment: 5я строка `int i = 1;` что она делает? Вы используете ее, как ключ для доступа к элементам массива, но она у Вас все время равна 1.

Comment: Это индекс массива, для наглядности, если даже вместо него нарисовать цикл for  c увеличением на 1, код не дает ожидаемого результата, пытаюсь понять где ошибка

Comment: Вы сравниваете res.equals(re), при этом res заполняется " Привет" на каждой итерации, внутрь if никогда не попадете. Вообще зачем использовать StringBuffer?

Comment: При args[0], тоже почему то не попадаю, хотя должен, StringBuffer для форматирования из args[i] в String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dublicate {
    public void delDublicate(String[] args) {
        for (int i = args.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            result.append(args[i]);
            String res = result.toString();
            for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
                StringBuffer esult = new StringBuffer();
                esult.append(args[j]);
                String re = esult.toString();
                if (i != j) {
                    if (res.equals(re)) {
                        args[i] = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] res = {"Привет", "Привет", "задание", "выполнено", "верно", "задание"};
        Dublicate dub = new Dublicate();
        dub.delDublicate(res);
        System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(res));
    }
}
```

Comment: Убрал пробелы, не помогло

Comment: как предлагаешь написать НЕ РАВНО с применением equals? Мне нужно сравнить индексы а не значения, значения я сравниваю здесь: res.equals(re), т.е. одинаковые значения в разных индексах

Comment: !str1.equals(str2) вот твое не равно. И уточни, какие индексы сравниваешь здесь: args[j]!= args[i] ? Посмотри здесь про сравнение строк http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/Как-сравнивать-строки-в-java

Comment: сравниваю индексы i и j, хоть так i!=j, хоть так  
!args[i].equals(args(j)), хоть так args[i]!=args(j), результат один, не здесь похоже ошибка

Comment: Обновил ответ, там рабочий код измененного твоего примера.

Comment: Между циклами бесполезный код инициализации объекта StringBuffer и перегон его обратно в строку

Comment: Я согласен, что можно было бы сделать по другому. Я просто сделал его код - рабочим кодом, без больших изменений, а дальше уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог!

Answer (score 5):

Я бы сделал примерно так

```
public String[]delDublicate(String[] args) {
    List<String> withoutDublicate = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String str : args) {
        if (!withoutDublicate.contains(str)) {
            withoutDublicate.add(str);
        }
    }

    String[] returnArr = new String[withoutDublicate.size()];
    return withoutDublicate.toArray(returnArr);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String [] res={" Привет ", " Привет", " задание", " выполнено", " верно", " задание"};
    Dublicate dub=new Dublicate();
    String[] arr = dub.delDublicate(res);
    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(arr));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
 String[] res = {"Привет", "Привет", "задание", "выполнено", "верно", "задание"};
 String[] array = Arrays.stream(res).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```