# Помогите разобраться с логикой

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка открыть в браузере. Но я сделал ограничение на некоторые ограничения чтобы нельзя было открыть локальные файлы. Но после нажатия приложение пытается их запустить. Где моя ошибка?

```
if (mWebView.getUrl() == "file:///android_asset/moreinfoapp.html"){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.err_obrow_1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
} else if (mWebView.getUrl() == "file:///android_asset/errnoconnect.html"){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.err_obrow_1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
} else {
    Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mWebView.getUrl()));
    startActivity(browseIntent);
}
```

Comment: строки разве не через s1.equals(s2) сравниваются?

Comment: посмотрите этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String urlbrowser = mWebView.getUrl();
        if(urlbrowser.equals("file:///android_asset/moreinfoapp.html")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.err_obrow_1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if (urlbrowser.equals("file:///android_asset/errnoconnect.html")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.err_obrow_1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mWebView.getUrl()));
            startActivity(browseIntent);
        }
```

Неправильно Сравнивал. [Подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java)