# Как узнать значение строки?

Tags: java

```
String PA;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "Cp866");

PA = in.nextLine();
```

Не могу узнать значение `PA` если при вводе я нажму Enter ничего не введя.

Пробовал `if(PA == "") out.print("==");` `if(PA == null) out.print("==");` Задавать null при объявлении.

Решил проблему проверкой строки isEmpty().

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы сравниваете строки **по ссылке**. Выражение вида `str==""` для строки которую считали из консоли, будет давать всегда `false`
Для желаемого результата нужно использовать, либо метод `equals`, либо `isEmpty`

Comment: А какое будет значение у переменной? Null или пусто("")? IsEmpty?

Comment: у меня пустая строка пришла

Comment: Удалось проверить на isEmpty

Comment: То есть с if можно проверить переменную на false?

Comment: конечно, если напишите if(!false) ...

Comment: Наоборот if(PA == false), строка пуста. Хотя если вместо false вписать имя переменной то да. А строку нельзя так проверить видимо. (!PA)

Comment: нет, в java такое не прокатывает. строка это строка а не булево значение, и операции отрицания, либо какие то еще не применимы к ней.