# Основы Java. Как работает nextLine. Или не nextLine

Tags: java

Есть такой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoobsIm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean continueWhile = true;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("> ");
            String inputText = inp.nextLine();
            if (inputText == "m") {
                System.out.println("сработало");
                continueWhile = false;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("не сработало");
            }
        } while (continueWhile);

    }
}
```

И, если честно, делает какую-то ерунду! Ввожу "m" — выводит "не сработало". Ввожу "Что-то там" — выводит то же самое.

Comment: Используйте для сравнения строк метод `equals`, а не оператор `==`.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, а можно несколько более подробней?

Comment: Подробнее можно прочитать, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/183458).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оператор сравнения `==` в Java возвращает `true` либо при сравнении примитивных типов имеющих одинаковые значения, либо при сравнении двух одинаковых объектов (ссылок на один и тот же объект). В вашем случае два объекта типа `String` являются разными, хоть и содержат внутри себя одинаковые данные.

Для сравнения объектов используют оператор `equals()`, где он реализован. Т.е. в вашем случае надо делать так:

```
if(inputText.equals("m")){
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.