# Как проверить наличие текста в EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

Есть два `EditText` и кнопка отправки с методом `onClick()`.
При нажатии на кнопку в методе срабатывает код отправки данных из полей на сервер.
Нужно проверить количество символов на минимально допустимое значение (6 символов). И проверить что оба поля `EditText` не пустые.

Вот мой код:

```
user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

l_user = user.getText().toString();
p_user = password.getText().toString();

if (l_user == "") {
    setContentView(R.layout.act_login);
}
else {
    if (p_user == "") {
        setContentView(R.layout.act_login);
    }
    else {
        // код отправки данных из форм на сервер
```

Этот способ проверки на заполнение почему-то работает некорректно. Если пусты оба поля, то все работает, а если в одно из полей ввести букву, то скрипт начинает отправлять запрос. А ведь не должен, ибо второе поле-то пустое!
По коду видно, что если хотя бы одно из полей пустое, грузится экран с той же формой регистрации, но, как я сказал, проверка плохо работает.

Как правильно сделать проверку на количество символов, введенных в поле `EditText`?

Comment: [Как сравнивать строки в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java)

Comment: @eugeneek однако при этом автор утверждает, что если оба поля пустые, то запрос не уходит. И вот это кажется странным.

Comment: зачем дважды setContentView(R.layout.act_login);?

Comment: @iFr0z а зачем строки сравнивать через `==` без веских на то причин?

Comment: а в вашем случае `"".equals(l_user)`, что проверит на пустоту вернет `false`, даже когда `l_user == null`.

Comment: @Regent я чтоль такое сделал?

Comment: @LexHobbit сомневаюсь, что `.getText().toString()` может кончиться `null`-ом.

Comment: @iFr0z нет. Просто по коду понятно, что автор - новичок в этом деле, поэтому и `==` у него, и условия не объединены в один `if`. Поэтому смысла в вопросе _"зачем дважды setContentView(R.layout.act_login);?"_ я не вижу: вроде и так понятно почему автор так сделал (в меру своих умений). Поэтому какой толк от этого вопроса? Если хотите намекнуть на объединение условий, то лучше это сделать в утвердительной форме и с примером.

Comment: @Regent ваша правда... а вот `findViewById` может

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вам не нужно сравнивать строки, проще проверять количество символов в строке. Как то так:

```
if (l_user.length() > 5 && p_user.length() > 5) {
   // код отправки данных из форм на сервер
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, роботает!

Answer (score 6):

А зачем вообще преобразовывать в строки? Все и так отлично работает:

```
if (user.getText().length() == 0 || password.getText().length() == 0) {
  setContentView(R.layout.act_login);
} else {
  // код отправки данных из форм на сервер
}
```

Меньше кода, легче читать.

Comment: про ограничения длинны укажите еще

Comment: на минимально допустимое значение (6 символов)

Comment: @LexHobbit так вроде так сейчас в ответе и есть? Слово "длина", кстати, с одной "н".

Comment: Из вопроса не совсем ясно что проверять на минимум 6 символов.

Comment: @Regent все верно =) все пора отдыхать...

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja верно, вот автор удивится, когда узнает, что у EditText можно еще и максимальную длину установить и пароль скрывать =)

Comment: > И посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как сделать проверку на количество символов, введенных в поле  EditText. < Как раз спрашивает. Так что возвращайте вариант с < 6)) Точнее <= 6

Answer (score 1):

Проверять строки на пустоту следует следующим образом:

```
if(l_user.equals(""))
{
    //строка пуста
}
```

Вот вам чтиво на эту тему: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/string.php#equals

Answer (score 1):

Я зделал так чтобы не пропускало только пробелы

```
String text = edittext.getText().toString();
   String[] arr = text.split(""); 
   Boolean isEmpty = true;

   for (String arg: arr){ // проверяем посимвольно
       if(arg.equals(""))
           isEmpty = true; // в массиве первый елемент всегда "", я не нашел для себя способа его удалить.
       else if(!arg.equals(" ")){
           isEmpty = false;
       }
   }
   if (isEmpty || text.equals("")){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Поле пустое", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   }
   else 
       // код дальше
```

Думаю поможет)