# Properties или с чем его едят

Tags: java

Можно ли работать со значениями в текстовом файле properties?

Например считать значение и добавить его в логические операции?

Если нет, то с помощью чего можно прочитать и поработать со значениями в текстовом файле?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try {
            props.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
String answer = props.getProperty("OTBET");
if(answer == "4") System.out.print("answer = 4");
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу сравнить, ничего не происходит!

Comment: да, можно. в чем возникла проблема у вас ?

Comment: Properties props = new Properties();
try {
   props.load(in);
  } catch (IOException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
String answer = props.getProperty("OTBET");
if(answer == "4")

Проблема в том, что я не могу сравнить, ничего не происходит

Comment: [как сравнивать строки в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417406/177345)

Comment: @Митяй `answer.equals("4")` надо. строки через == не сравниваются

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/propertiesfile.properties"));
String str = properties.getProperty("a.string"); //str ="test string from property file"
```

Property file:

```
a.string=test string from property file
```