# сравнение строки и символа java

Tags: java, сравнение

Как заставить это работать?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char g = '\n';
        String gil = "\n";
        if(gil == String.valueOf(g)) System.out.print("HERE");
        if(gil == (g+"")) System.out.print("HERE");

    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Roman, зачем задавать подобные вопросы, если ответ можно найти по первой ссылке в Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сравнивать `g == gil.charAt(0)` не вариант?

Comment: @Roman это вы берете первый символ строки и сравнивает его с вашим символом, суть примерно обратна тому, что пытаетесь сделать вы. Это будет правильным решением

Answer (score 3):

Строка в `Java` - это не примитив, а объект. И даже если значения двух строк одинаковые, `id` все равно будут разные. Для сравнения объектов существует метод `equals()` в нашем случае класса `String`. Из аннотации к нему следует, что 2 строки сравниваются посимвольно (если это вообще 2 строки):

> Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is {@code
>      true} if and only if the argument is not {@code null} and is a {@code
>      String} object that represents the same sequence of characters as this
>      object.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char g = '\n';
        String gil = "\n";
        if(gil.equals(String.valueOf(g))) System.out.print("HERE");
        if(gil.equals(g+"")) System.out.print("HERE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать эту проверку как отдельный метод, все таки неизвестно понадобится еще или нет, а так не будет дублирования кода.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char g = '\n';
        String gil = "\n";
        if(isSame(gill, g)) System.out.print("HERE");
    }

    public boolean isSame(String string, Char char){
        if(string != null && char != null && string.length == 1){
            return string.charAt(0) == char;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```