# некорректный вывод значений, используя SharedPreference

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Имеется такой набор "константных" строк:

```
final String SAVE_STRING_BIRTHDAY_DATA = "";
final String SAVE_STRING_NAME = "";
```

и объект класса `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences shPref;
```

в методе `OnCreate()` вызывается функция `LoadData()`:

```
private void LoadData() {
        shPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedBirthdayDate = shPref.getString(SAVE_STRING_BIRTHDAY_DATA,"");
        String savedFirstName = shPref.getString(SAVE_STRING_NAME,"");

        tv_date.setText(savedBirthdayDate);
        editText_FirstName.setText(savedFirstName);

        if (editText_FirstName.getText().toString() != "")
            editText_FirstName.setEnabled(false);

        if (tv_date.getText().toString() != "")
            tv_date.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Предположим, что по ключу `SAVE_STRING_BIRTHDAY_DATA` уже записано значение "08/07/2018". Тогда при запуске приложения в **TextView** `tv_date` будет установлено значение "08/07/2018" и данный View-элемент будет не активен, в то время как **EditText** `editText_FirstName` будет пустым и доступным для ввода. Но когда я запускаю приложение, почему-то аналогичное значение записывается и в `editText_FirstName`, становясь также неактивным.

Помогите разобраться, в чём причина.

Comment: А у Вас реально константам присвоены пустые строки? Если да, то они эквивалентны и для преференсов это один и тот же ключ и храниться будет то значение, которое записано последним. Задайте константам разные значения.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, помогло. Единственное только, почему теперь выполняется условие первое, хотя когда в дебагере отлаживаю, то чётко вижу, что в EditText сейчас лежит пустая строка, то есть "".

Comment: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/11515)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас константам присвоены пустые строки и они эквивалентны.
Для преференсов это один и тот же ключ и храниться будет то значение, которое записано последним.
Нужно присвоить константам разные значения:

```
final String SAVE_STRING_BIRTHDAY_DATA = "SAVE_STRING_BIRTHDAY_DATA ";
final String SAVE_STRING_NAME          = "SAVE_STRING_NAME";
```

Comment: Да-да, всё заработало, спасибо!