# Не проходит проверка на схожесть текста в двух переменных

Tags: java, строки, текст

Решил создать программу. Что -то вроде Алисы. Но когда проходит проверка введёного текста на другое слово, ничего не происходит.Вот код:

```
package com.speaker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.speaker.R;

public class MainActivitySpeaker extends Activity {
    EditText submitText;
    Button submitButton;
    TextView submitShowIn;
    TextView submitShowOut;
    Editable text;
    CharSequence text2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_speaker);
        submitText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEdit);
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idSubmit);
        submitShowIn = (TextView)     findViewById(R.id.idShowIn);
        submitShowOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idShowOut);
    }

    public void onSubmit(View v){
        text = submitText.getText();
        submitShowIn.setText(text);
        submitText.setText("");

        if (String.valueOf(text) == "Привет"){
            submitShowOut.setText("Привет!");
        }
    }
}
```

submitText - это введёный текст.
submitShowIn - это блок, куда вписывается введёный текст по нажатию кнопки submitButton.
submitShowOut - это блок, куда должен вписываться ответ бота.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что уже написали покажете?

Comment: Drakonoved, это разработка российской компнии Яндекс, искусственный интеллект, встроенный в приложение "Яндекс с Алисой", который со смыслом отвечает на поставленные вопросы и в устной, и в письменной форме. Посмотрите в Интернете и в Play Market

Comment: ==  замените на equals и прочитайте, как сравнивать строки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java