# Как вытащить объект enum по значению?

Tags: java, enum

Есть код (ниже). Мне нужно вытащить MOSCOW по uid. Как возможно сделать?

```
public enum Region {
        MOSCOW("Москва", 77, "0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5"),
        MOSKOVSKAYAOBLAST("Московская область", 50, "29251dcf-00a1-4e34-98d4-5c47484a36d4");

        private final String label;
        private final Integer codeRegion;
        private final String uid;

        Region(String label, Integer codeRegion, String uid) {
            this.label = label;
            this.codeRegion = codeRegion;
            this.uid = uid;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Нужно переписать код, добавив метод getUid()

Comment: Как нужно переписать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так получилось:

```
public static Region getNameByCode(String code){
        for(Region e : Region.values()){
            if(code == e.getUid())
                return e;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java

Answer (score 2):

Возможно есть более прямые способы, но чтобы каждый раз не перебирать весь список можно сделать карту и метод `getRegByUid(String uid)`

```
    public enum Region {
    MOSCOW("Москва", 77, "0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5"),
    MOSKOVSKAYAOBLAST("Московская область", 50, "29251dcf-00a1-4e34-98d4-5c47484a36d4");

    private final String label;
    private final Integer codeRegion;
    private final String uid;

    // карта
    private static Map<String, Region> map = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Region region : Region.values()){
            map.put(region.uid, region);
        }
    }

    // get по uid
    public static Region getRegByUid(String uid) {
        return map.get(uid);
    }

    Region(String label, Integer codeRegion, String uid) {
        this.label = label;
        this.codeRegion = codeRegion;
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Region {
     MOSCOW{
        @Override
        public  String getUid(){
            return "0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5";
        }
    }


public abstract  String getUid();
}
```

Comment: Мне сам регион нужно вытащить - MOSCOW по uid. Решил кодом ниже