# Оператор if внутри else

Tags: java, if

Написал данный код, он что то не работает:

```
   int system = 0;

     String nick0="Артём";
    String nick0L="artem";
    String nick0P="1996";

     String nick1="Сергей";
    String nick1L="sergo";
    String nick1P="1991";

    String nick2="Николай";
   String nick2L="nikola2";
   String nick2P="bestpass";

    String nick3="Андрей";
   String  nick3L="andry";
   String nick3P="1234";

    String nick4="Алексей";
   String  nick4L="alex";
   String nick4P="xela";

    String nick5="Маша";
   String nick5L="mash1992";
   String nick5P="1992";

    String nick6="Роман";
   String nick6L="roma";
   String nick6P="987654321";

   String name = "name";

    System.out.println("Please, login");
   if (login==nick0L){
        system=1;
   name=nick0; }
   else
        if (login == nick1L) {
            system = 1;
            name = nick1;}
         else
    if (login==nick2L){
        system=1;
        name=nick2; }
        else
    if (login==nick3L){
        system=1;
        name=nick3; }
        else
    if (login==nick4L){
        system=1;
        name=nick4; }
        else
    if (login==nick5L){
        system=1;
        name=nick5; }
        else
    if (login==nick6L){
        system=1;
        name=nick6; }
    else
    {System.out.println("Error name");}




    System.out.println(system);
    System.out.println("You login as "+name);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: В Джаве строки сравниваются методом `.equals()` класса `String`.
На ваш вопрос уже был дан ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод equals(), так как строки являются объектами.

```
if (login.equals(name0L)) {
...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо ребят, помогли :-)

Comment: @FussionBart Не забывайте отмечать ответы как принятые.