# Не правильно работает код (новичок)

Tags: java

Есть программа:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Привет, могу чем-то помочь?");
        String text =  num.nextLine();

      if (text == "Да") {
          System.out.println("Чем конкретно?");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Не поняла ваш ответ, повторите");
      }
   }
}
```

Изначально выводится текст "Привет, могу чем-то помочь?", после чего я в консоли пишу "Да" и в итоге постоянно выводит ("Не поняла ваш ответ, повторите"), вместо нужного ("Чем конкретно?").

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Насколько я помню, в java строки сравнивают методом equals

Comment: @Max Ваша правка несомненно полезная, но вопрос после неё попадает в очередь на переоткрытие. И как проверяющие должны решать?

Comment: @СашаЧерных Вы считаете, что это не дубликат? Почему? Спасибо.

Comment: @0xdb, Я считаю что ответ нельзя считать дубликатом, потому что вопрос не был поставлен так: "как сравнивать строки в Java". Автор не знал что проблема в сравнении строк. А ответом нужно указать что ошибка в сравнении строк и дать ссылку на [Как сравнить строки в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/Как-сравнивать-строки-в-java)
Так же советую посмотреть [данную статью](https://lesswrong.ru/w/Знание_задним_числом), я думаю в этом кроется причина, почему данный ответ хочется пометить как дубликат.