# Проверка на вводимый параметр String[] args

Tags: java, строки, print

Есть такой код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args[0] == "hi")
            System.out.println("Hello");
        else
            System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

Как видите я хочу, чтобы после запуска с скомпилированным выше кодом файл *Main.class*, с параметром *hi*, в терминал выводилось сообщение `Hello`, но выводится `Bye`. **Почему?**

Comment: `if ("hi".equals(args[0]))`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод `equals` для сравнения двух строк, которые создаются во время выполнения.

Рассмотрите эту программу

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "Run-time String definition:" );    

        String s1 = "He";
        String s2 = "llo";

        System.out.println( s1 + s2 == "Hello" );
        System.out.println( ( s1 + s2 ).equals( "Hello" ) );

        System.out.println( "\nCompile-time String definition:" );  

        String s3 = "Hello";

        System.out.println( s3 == "Hello" );
        System.out.println( s3.equals( "Hello" ) );

    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
Run-time String definition:
false
true

Compile-time String definition:
true
true
```