# Тип данных String и StringBuilder.toString()

Tags: java, android, строки

Имеется

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(".");
```

из которого я преспокойно делаю

```
String s = sb.toString();
```

затем я хочу сравнить полученную строку s с "." и, если это так, обнулить sb:

```
if (s == "."){sb.setLength(0);}
```

Видно, что если sb = ".", то и s = ".", не так ли? Но вместо пустого sb получаю sb = ".".
Прошу, умоляю вас объяснить, почему:

```
s != "."
```

Спасибо за всякую помощь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод equals(".") вместо ==.