# Scanner неправильно считывает строку

Tags: java

```
public class Proverka {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = in.nextLine();

    if (x == "Ок"){
        System.out.println("Сработало");
    }
    else System.out.println("Не сработало");
}
```

Есть код. При вводе "Ок", программа выводит текст: "Не сработало". В чём проблема?
Новичок, гуглил, решения не нашел (либо плохо гуглил).
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравнивайте объекты на эквивалентное значение через метод [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Т.е. так:

```
if (x.equals("Ок")) {
```

Оператор `==` для сложных объектов (строки среди них) сравнивает ссылки у объектов. Простые же типы (`int`, 'float', 'boolean', и т.п.) оператором `==` сравниваются по значению.

---

**PS.**

Чтобы узнать идентификатор у объектов используйте [System.identityHashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)).
Уверен, если вы введете такое же значение, что в литеральной константе, то метод [System.identityHashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) вернет разные значения, при том, что [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) будет `true`:

```
String x = in.nextLine(); // "Ok"

System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(x) == System.identityHashCode("Ok")); // false
System.out.println(x.equals("Ok")); // true
```