# Что я сделал не так, что строка не проходит проверку?

Tags: java, строки

Я пытаюсь сделать запароленный шифровщик файлов, но почему-то строка, инициализированная с помощью инпут-диалога JOptionPane, не проходит проверку. Я пробовал её вывести без проверки, и она была равна строке password.

```
     String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"something","title",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
     if (password=="pass"){
          System.out.println("pass");
```

Comment: Строки обычно сравниваются через password.equals("pass");

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java нельзя сравнивать строки оператором `==`

Вместо вашего сравнения напишите `if("pass".equals(password))`

Comment: Да почему нельзя-то? Можно. Только сравниваться будет другое.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!