# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException к чему это

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Язык: Java, IDE: IJ2020.3

Грубо говоря ввожу строку: gryffindor
Должен получить ответ:     bravery

Но появляется ошибка:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Сам код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String house = scanner.next();
        switch (house) {
            case "gryffindor":
                System.out.println("bravery");
                break;
            case "hufflepuff":
                System.out.println("loyalty");
                break;
            case "slytherin":
                System.out.println("cunning");
                break;
            case "ravenclaw":
                System.out.println("intellect");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("not a valid house");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Код прошел проверку на курсе от JetBrains успешно. Вроде всё просто, но не могу понять в чём дело. Считываю строку. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Приложите именно тот код, который вызывает ошибку. Этот код указанную ошибку вызвать не может

Comment: Антон, добрый день, после Ваших слов я понял, что данный код надо было попробовать запустить в другом компиляторе. Я действительно получал данную ошибку при выполнении данной программы. Спасибо!

Comment: Нет не получали. Вы эту ошибку получали с другим кодом

Comment: А еще почитайте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java и не удивляйтесь, если ваш код работать не будет