# Как сравнить последнюю букву строки с другой буквой

Tags: java, substring

Хочу сравнить последнюю букву в слове с другой буквой.

```
String str = "гол";
if (str.substring(str.length()-1)=="л")
```

ошибку не дает но я подозреваю что неправильно

Comment: на чем основано подозрение?

Comment: Так красивее: `if (str.endsWith("л")) {`

Comment: Чтобы работало правильно, нужно сравнивать через `.equals()`. А так да - используйте `endsWith`.

Comment: а как найти предпоследнюю, str.length()-1 - так я могу обратится и к последней и предпоследней  str.length()-2

Comment: не печатает в консоль String str = requestString() ;

       if (str.substring(str.length()-1)=="л"&& str.substring(str.length()-2)=="о"){
           System.out.println("правильно");   Просто завершается
       }

Answer (score 1):

Вкратце, почему не работает сравнение в вашем коде: строка (`String`) - это ссылочный тип, сравнение через `==` для ссылочных типов проверяет равенство ссылок, а не равенство содержимого. Для ссылочных типов сравнение через `==` даст `true` только если это один и тот же объект. Примеры смотрите в этом ответе: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417406/1365)

Для сравнения по содержимому используйте метод `equals` (на примере вашего кода):

```
String str = "гол";
if (str.substring(str.length()-1).equals("л")) {
    System.out.println("Строка заканчивается на л");
}
```

Рекомендую почитать про разницу примитивных и ссылочных типов в Java.

Далее, если нужно проверить одиночный символ, а не подстроку, можно использовать метод [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)):

```
String str = "гол";
if (str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'л') {
    System.out.println("Строка заканчивается на л");
}
```

`charAt` возвращает значение примитивного типа `char`, поэтому тут сравнение через `==` (попытка сравнения через `equals` вызовет ошибку компиляции).

Соответственно, чтобы получить предпоследний символ, используйте `str.charAt(str.length()-2)`.

Если нужно проверить, что строка заканчивается на определенную последовательность символов (судя по коду в комментариях к вопросу, вы это пытаетесь сделать), то вместо посимвольного сравнения лучше использовать метод [`endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) (метод проверяет, что строка заканчивается на указанную подстроку, возвращает `true` если да, иначе `false`):

```
String str = "гол";
if (str.endsWith("ол")) {
    System.out.println("Строка заканчивается на ол");
}
```

https://ideone.com/7hK0iP

Answer (score 0):

нужно через иквалс сравнивать строки!

```
String str = "гол"
if (str.substring(str.length()-1).equals("л"))
```

чтобы сравнить предпоследний символ - вот так используется

```
String str = "гол"
if (str.substring(str.length()-2, str.length()-1).equals("о"))
```