# Помогите с вводом данных на Java

Tags: java, ввод

Я в Java новичок. Описал ввод данных, засунул в цикл, задал условие. Объясните почему в коде игнорируется проверка?

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Writer {

    public static boolean isTrue;
    public static String lines="";
    public static String line="";

    public static void writer() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("new.txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        isTrue = true;
        while (isTrue==true) {
            line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line == "!q") {
                isTrue = false;
                break;
            } else {
                lines+=line;
                System.out.println("Целое предложение = " + lines);
            }
        }
        in.close();
        writer.println(lines);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java), в строке `line == "!q"` нужно использовать `equals/equalsIgnoreCase`: `if ("!q".equals(line))`

Answer (score 0):

hasNext() помог. Достаточно было побольше почитать, а не панику разводить