# проверка пароля в java

Tags: java, android

Использую код написанный на Java. Нужно проверить, совпадают ли введенные пароли. Написал для этого условие в onCreate, но при запуске приложение Toast вылезает совершенно на другом активити и не отображается в нужном.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        init();

        if(password.getText().toString() == secondPassword.getText().toString()){
            System.out.println("5");
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Введенные пароли не совпадают", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public EditText nick, date, email, password, secondPassword;
    public Button go;

    private void init(){
        nick = findViewById(R.id.PersonNick);
        date = findViewById(R.id.Date);
        email = findViewById(R.id.EmailAddress);
        password = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        secondPassword = findViewById(R.id.SecondPassword);
        go = findViewById(R.id.go);
    }
}
```

Comment: Строки сравниваются не так, и у вас поля ввода не инициализированы

Comment: И как же проинициализировать поля ввода. Можете приложить код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого необходимо инициализировать переменную. Делал я это сразу в слушателе нажатий на кнопку

```
     private void init(){
            nick = findViewById(R.id.PersonNick);
            date = findViewById(R.id.Date);
            email = findViewById(R.id.EmailAddress);
            password = findViewById(R.id.Password);
            secondPassword = findViewById(R.id.SecondPassword);
            go = findViewById(R.id.go);
            textPrivacyPolicy = findViewById(R.id.textPrivacyPolicy);
        }
        public void conreg(View view){
тут инициализируем переменные. 
            String firstPass = password.getText().toString();
            String secondPass = secondPassword.getText().toString();
            String username = nick.getText().toString();
            String userDate = date.getText().toString();
            String mailpochta = email.getText().toString();
                    // проверка полей на заполненность
                if (username.length() == 0 || userDate.length() == 0 || mailpochta.length() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Поля не могут быть пустыми", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    if (firstPass.equals(secondPass) & firstPass.length() != 0 & secondPass.length() != 0){     // проверка паролей на соответствии друг с другом и наличие его
                        // data get database
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Введенные пароли не совпадают", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Во-первых:** [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/11515) - там всё достаточно разжёвано. В общем случае следует использовать `equals()`.

**Во-вторых:** в `onCreate()` вью элементы ещё даже не видны на экране, а тем более в них не введено никакого текста. Код обработки паролей следует переместить в слушатель кнопки подтверждения/перехода. Либо установить слушатель фокуса на `EditText` и проверять при потере, то есть когда юзер переходит к другому элементу. Либо, если требуется проверять на лету по мере ввода, установить слушатель ввода на `EditText` и проверку поместить туда.