# Не приравнивается jsonobject.getString() к string

Tags: android

Существует массив в нём есть переменная либо **right** либо **lef**t. Получаю этот массив и переделываю в `jsonobject`. Далее идёт код проверки:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
if(jsonObject.getString("yourid") == "left"){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "jhd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Он не выводит сообщение хотя я уверен что там **left** так как я отдельно от него же получаю в текст left. Затем я попробовал ввести в массив переменные **left** и **right** как отдельные для проверки и вызвал код:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
if(jsonObject.getString("yourid") == jsonObject.getString("left")) {                                    
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "jhd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Но и тут опять ничего не выдаёт. В чём может быть проблема.

P.S. Получаю массив из ответа на `POST` запрос.

Comment: Думаю вам туда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/11515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сравнения можно использовать

```
jsonObject.getString("yourid").equals("left")
```