# Как проверить значение EditText на соответствие String значению

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, проверялось значение **EditText** на соответствие *month*, и в  **Textview**, при соответствии, передалось 30. Я попытался `if(editText1.getText().toString() == "month") {Textview.setText ("30")} else {Textview.setText ("0")}`.  Выводит собственно 0.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: `Textview.setText("month".equals(editText1.getText()) ? "30" : "0");`

Comment: Строки нельзя сравнивать оператором `==`, их нужно сравнивать **только** с помощью метода `equals()`, который определён в классе `java.lang.Object`. Оператор `==` подходит только для сравнения примитивных типов. А если вы попытаетесь сравнить две строки с помощью `==`, то будут сравниваться не сами строки, а их места в памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки соответствия строки используйте метод equals:

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().equals("month")) {
    Textview.setText("30");
} else {
    Textview.setText("0");
}
```