# Реализовать методы

Tags: java

boolean isWeekend(String dayName) - метод принимает строку и отвечает, является ли данная строка выходным днем. Выходным днем являются Sunday и Saturday.

2. int weekendCount(String[] days) - метод принимает массив строк и возвращает количество выходных дней в этом массиве.
3. int weekdayCount(String[] days) - метод принимает массив строк и возвращает количество будних дней в этом массиве.

   ```
    public static boolean isWeekend(String dayName) {
    if (dayName == "Monday") {
        return false;
    } else if (dayName == "Tuesday") {
        return false;
    } else if (dayName == "Wednesday") {
        return false;
    } else if (dayName == "Thursday") {
        return false;
    } else if (dayName == "Friday") {
        return false;
    } else if (dayName == "Saturday") {
        return true;
    } else return dayName == "Sunday";
    }

    public static int weekendCount(String[] days) {

    int weekend = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < days.length; i++) {
        if (isWeekend(days[i])) {
            weekend++;
        }

    }
    return weekend;

   }

    public static int weekdayCount(String[] days) {
    int weekday =0;
    for (int i = 1 ; i < days.length; i++)
    {
        if (isWeekend(days[i])) {
            weekday++;
        }
    }
    return weekday;
    }
   ```

   Тест провален. Некорректная реализация метода weekendCount. В массиве было 3 выходных

Comment: 1) Не сравнивайте строки оператором `==` 2) Опишите подробней, в чём проблема.

Comment: Мне надо с помощью метода isWeekend определить является ли данная строка выходным днем, а потом с помощью этого метода в методе weekendCount вернуть количество выходных дней. А в методе weekdayCount количество будних дней

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Достаточно проверить, равна ли входная строка `"Sunday"` или `"Saturday"` (без учёта регистра), ещё пять проверок для будних дней не обязательны.
2. Нумерация индексов для массивов начинается с 0, а не с 1, нужно будет исправить циклы в методах `weekendCount`, `weekdayCount`, или вообще лучше использовать цикл `foreach`, чтобы не ошибаться в индексах.

Также можно передавать массивы в методы в виде vararg аргументов (с многоточием), тогда можно упростить вызовы таких методов.

```java
public static boolean isWeekend(String dayName) {
    return "Saturday".equalsIgnoreCase(dayName) || "Sunday".equalsIgnoreCase(dayName );
}

public static int weekendCount(String ... days) {
    int weekend = 0;
    for (String day : days) {
        if (isWeekend(day)) {
            weekend++;
        }
    }
    return weekend;
}
```

Вариант с использованием Stream API:

```java
public static int weekdayCount(String ... days) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(days).filter(d -> !isWeekend(d)).count();
}
```