# трудность с if else

Tags: java, android-shared-preferences

у меня возникла трудность с if else

переменная lal = 0
и я хочу её сравнить
Если 0 = 0 то выведет 0, но почему-то выводит 1

```
blocker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String lal = appPreferences.getString("blackout", "");

                if (lal == 0)
                {
                    textView.append("0");
                }
                else
                {
                    textView.append("1");
                }
                }
        });
```

Comment: Ваша переменная строковая, а не числовая. А сравнивать строки нужно другим способом. Например `equals`.

Comment: да и сравнивать строки нужно со строкой, а не с числом.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы читаете переменную методом `.getString();`. Это означает, что в `lal` у вас строка, а не число. Строку нужно сравнивать а) со строкой, б) используя метод `equals()`:

```
if (lal.equals("0"))
```

Если какие-то сохраняемые настройки у вас могут быть только число, то можно и сохранть их как число, а потом читать как число. Записать:

```
appPreferences.putInt("blackout", 0); // переменная blackout теперь целое число
```

Прочитать:

```
appPreferences.getInt("blackout", null);
```

Тогда можно сравнивать как у вас

```
if (lal == 0)
```