# Java почему то не видит изменения при вводе римских цифр

Tags: java, swift, классы, if, калькулятор

Написала код, с арабскими цифрами работает корректно, но на римские цифры ругается, пишет что не те числа введены

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TrowExeprion {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите пример, где значения вводятся через пробел");
        String calc = in.nextLine();
        String[] c = calc.split(" ");
        String[] c1 = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};
        String num1 = c[0];
        String num2 = c[2];
        int k1=0;
        int k2=0;
        int first = 0;
        int second = 0;
        int x1 = 0;
        String x2 = "0";
        if (num1.equals("1") |num1.equals("2") | num1.equals("3") | num1.equals("4") | num1.equals("5") |num1.equals("6") | num1.equals("7") | num1.equals("8") | num1.equals("9") | num1.equals("10") ){
            first = Integer.valueOf(num1);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i<c1.length; i++) {
                if (num1.equals(c1[i])) {
                    first = i + 1;
                    k1 = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (num2.equals("1") |num2.equals("2") | num2.equals("3") | num2.equals("4") | num2.equals("5") |num2.equals("6") | num2.equals("7") | num2.equals("8") | num2.equals("9") | num2.equals("10") ){
            second = Integer.valueOf(num2);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i<c1.length; i++) {
                if (num2.equals(c1[i])) {
                    first = i + 1;
                    k2 = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        int x = 0;
        if ((k1 == 0) && (k2 == 0)){
            switch (c[1]){
                case "+" :
                    x = first +second;
                    break;
                case "-" :
                    x = first - second;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    x = first * second;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    x = first / second;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if ((k1 == 0) && (k2 == 1)){
            throw new TrowExeprion();
        }
        else if ((k1 == 1) && (k2 == 0)){
            throw new TrowExeprion();
        }
        else if ((k1 == 1) && (k2 == 1) && (first<=second)){
            throw new TrowExeprion();
        }
        else if ((k1 == 1) && (k2 == 1) && (first > second)){
            switch (c[1]){
                case "+" :
                    x = first +second;
                    break;
                case "-" :
                    x = first - second;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    x = first * second;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    x = first / second;
                    break;
            }
            x2 = c1[(x-1)];
        }

        if ((first >= 1) && (first <=10) && (second >= 1) && (second <=10) && (k1 == 1 ) && (k2 == 1)){
            System.out.println("Ваше получившееся число:");
            System.out.println(x2);
        } else if ((first >= 1) && (first <= 10) && (second >=1) && (second <= 10) && (k1 == 0) && (k2 == 0)){
            System.out.println("Ваше получившееся число:");
            System.out.println(x);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Числа не подходят");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Строки нельзя сравнивать оператарами `==` и `!=`. Подробнее: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: if (с[0].equals(c1[i])) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable с

Comment: А где у вас массив `c` объявлен?

Comment: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите пример, где значения вводятся через пробел");
        String calc = in.nextLine();
        String[] c = calc.split(" ");

Comment: Класса не может быть у переменной, если она не определена как Class.

Comment: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable first
  location: class Main

Comment: Не знаю как, но переписала заново так же и все заработало...

Comment: Мне вот интересно, что вы хотите совершить с помощью этого кода?  Это должен был быть калькулятор для одноразрядных десятичных чисел?

Comment: должен быть калькулятор для римских и арабских чисел, бОльшую часть кода исправила, теперь ошибка в самом конце и я совсем не понимаю почему

Comment: теперь работает с арабскими, но странно работает с римскими, в самом конце ошибка, не понимаю как ее решить

Comment: исправила код в посте, может поможете найти ошибку

Comment: Проблема последней версии кода при чтении римской цифры - скопировано присваивание `first = i + 1;` поэтому `second` остаётся 0.  Однако хотелось бы сделать ряд замечаний: 1) После изменений в вопросе все существующие ответы потеряли всякий смысл 2) Вы ведь собирались использовать перечисления для представления римских цифр в вашем прошлом вопросе,  тогда для ввода римских цифр хватило бы метода `Rim::valueOf()` 3) Логика вашего калькулятора при работе с римскими цифрами непонятная. 4) Представить результаты умножения двух чисел до 10 10-ю римскими цифрами невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о Java (не знаю как в swift, но должно быть похоже, как и во всех языках основанных на синтаксисе С), мне кажется Вы упускаете очень важную  концепцию - область видимости переменных.

Упрощенно Ваш код с точки зрения данной проблемы выглядит так:

```
if (true) {
  int nestedVariable = 1;
}
use(nestedVariable); ///< ERROR
```

т.е. переменная прекращает свое существование за пределами области видимости, т.е. за пределами блока `{ }` в котором она объявлена (не путать с инициализацией!).

сравните с предыдущим примером:

```
int nestedVariable;
if (true) {
  nestedVariable = 1;
}
use(nestedVariable); ///< OK
```

т.о. проблема решается вынесением объявления переменных на тот уровень где они используются (как Вам уже рекомендовали коллеги, но забыли пояснить почему это необходимо сделать).

упростив некоторые конструкции Ваш код может выглядеть примерно так (неясно откуда берутся c, k1, k2 поэтому они остаются как были, но в них могут быть ошибки, как в случае с условием `(c[0] == c1[i])` во втором цикле, возможно тут должно быть `(c[2] == c1[i])` или `(c[2] == c2[i])`):

```
    int first = switch (c[0]) {
        case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" -> Integer.valueOf(c[0]);
        default -> {
            int f = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<c1.length; i++) {
                if (c[0] == c1[i]) {
                    first = i + 1;
                    k1=1;
                }
            }
            yield f;
        }
    };

    int second = switch (c[2]) {
        case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" -> Integer.valueOf(c[2]);
        default -> {
            int s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<c1.length; i++) {
                if (c[2] == c1[i]) {
                    s = i + 1;
                    k2=1;
                }
            }
            yield s;
        }
    };

    int x = switch (c[1]){
        case "+" -> first +second;
        case "-" -> first - second;
        case "*" -> first * second;
        case "/" -> first / second;
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported operation: " + c[1]);
    };
```

---

ЗЫ:
сравнивать строки с помощью `==` или `!=` можно, если осторожно. т.е. надо помнить, что эти операторы сравнивают только указатель на экземпляр строки, и если вы *всегда* пользуетесь строкам из некого пула и *никогда* не создаете новых экземпляоров явно или неявно, то эти операторы можно использовать, НО в Вашем коде этого делать нельзя, потому что условие будет возвращать не то что Вы ожидаете если Вы будете сравнивать строки идентичные по содержанию но размещенные в разных экземплярах.

```
String s = new String("X");
boolean isNotX = (s != "X"); ///< true, потому что сравниваются разные объекты
String s1 = s;
boolean isNotSame = (s != s1); ///< false, потому что s и s1 указывают на один и тот же объект.
```

Comment: yield это что? java на ошибку указывает

Comment: java: illegal start of expression на строчку int first = switch (c[0]) {

Comment: yield и extended switch это новые конструкции языка. в Java 17 все должно работать.

Comment: java: illegal start of expression на строчку int first = switch (c[0])

Comment: ну Ок, если у Вас старая Java проигнорируйте пример и сконцентрируйтесь на понимании концепции области видимости переменных, тогда сами свой код легко исправите.

Comment: исправила код,, теперь работает корректно кроме концовки, как будто не видит значения переменных first и second, можете посмотреть обновленный код

Comment: да, теперь код намного понятнее (хотя и далёк от совершенства). Ошибка похоже из-за копи-паста во втором цикле: `first = i + 1; k2 = 1;` а должно быть `second = i + 1; k2 = 1;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. Если в какую-то ветку `if` код не попадёт, то значит переменная не будет объявлена. Например вы не учитываете тот факт, что в цикле в `if` может код не попасть никогда.

Объявите переменные вообще где-нибудь вне условий и задайте им дефолтные значения. Например 0.

---

И да, строки нельзя сравнивать оператарами `==` и `!=`, смотрите почему:

[Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/191482)

Comment: if (с[0].equals(c1[i])) java: cannot find symbol symbol: variable с

Comment: а почему может не попасть в ветку if?

Comment: как записать не равно тогда?

Comment: *"почему может не попасть в ветку if"* --- Потому что условие будет false. Ну логично же)  Интерпретатор не может быть уверен, что условие выполнится и поэтому говорит - давай до свиданья..... *"как записать не равно тогда?"*  --- восклицательный знак впереди было всегда отрицанием

Comment: переделала условие, но если я вношу значения до if, то почему то через if все равно не проходит и использует начальные значения

Comment: что значит *"вношу значения до if"* ?

Comment: int first = 0 и int second = 0 пишу до if, программа все равно не меняет значения в if

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [отладкой кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701413/191482), чтобы определить на каком этапе у вас интерпретатор куда заходит и какие значения у переменнных есть....

Comment: Есть вероятность, что надо писать `switch (true){`  а в `case` писать `c[1].equals("+")`  и с остальными знаками тоже

Comment: java: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int

Comment: нажимаю debug но программа просто начинает выполнятся до ошибки, хотя вроде делаю все по инструкции. Простите за тупые вопросы, я просто еще такой чайник, но очень хочу разобраться. на брейкпоинте не останавливается

Comment: было бы очень удобно, если бы могли это разобрать в голосе в каком-нибудь дискорде

Comment: *"boolean cannot be converted to int"* --- это вы как-то неправильно что-то написали...... кроме как увидеть код исправленный - не знаю что сказать.......... *"программа просто начинает выполнятся до ошибки"* --- там надо ставить breakpoint.  И лучше прям на первую строку программы. И дальше поэтапно смотреть.

Comment: ставлю breakpoint в самом начале программы, но дебаг это игнорирует и проходит по всей программе. Мы можем пожалуйста пойти в дискорд, чтобы лучше понять проблему?

Answer (score 0):

При условии, что существует простое перечисление с римскими цифрами, данный калькулятор проще реализовать с использованием следующих "фишек":

- Прочитать данные в именованные переменные при помощи`Scanner::next` вместо чтения строки `Scanner.nextLine` и разбиения на массив `String.split`
- Завести пару булевых переменных для определения состояния ввода: являются ли обе цифры обычными или римскими
- Для проверки "римских" цифр использовать `Enum::valueOf`, который выбросит "понятное" исключение для отсутствующего названия элемента.  Также для римских цифр должны быть ограничения на значение (от 1 до 10) и что первый операнд всегда больше второго, чтобы результат действия всегда был натуральным числом
- Вычислить результат, используя один `switch expression` по виду операции
- Вывести результат в нужном формате; для конвертации в римсккую цифру используются функции `Enum.values()` + `Enum::ordinal`

Вариант реализации (непедагогичная подсказка):

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите пример, где значения вводятся через пробел");
String arg1 = in.next().toUpperCase(), op = in.next(), arg2 = in.next().toUpperCase();

boolean isNum = arg1.matches("[2-9]|10?") && arg2.matches("[2-9]|10?");
boolean isRom = !isNum 
    && Roman.valueOf(arg1).value() < 11
    && Roman.valueOf(arg2).value() < 11;
    
if (!isNum && !isRom) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверные операнды: arg1=" + arg1 + "; arg2=" + arg2);
}

int a = isNum ? Integer.valueOf(arg1) : Roman.valueOf(arg1).value();
int b = isNum ? Integer.valueOf(arg2) : Roman.valueOf(arg2).value();
if (isRom && a <= b) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверные операнды для римских чисел: arg1=" + arg1 + "; arg2=" + arg2);
}
int res = switch(op) {
    case "+" -> a + b;
    case "-" -> a - b;
    case "/" -> a / b;
    case "*" -> a * b;
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверная операция " + op); 
};

System.out.println("Результат: " + (isNum ? res : Roman.values()[res - 1]));
```

Соответственно, код перечисления для римских чисел от 1 до 100 с дополнительным методом `int value`:

```java
enum Roman {
    I,     II,     III,     IV,     V,     VI,     VII,     VIII,     IX,    X,
   XI,    XII,    XIII,    XIV,    XV,    XVI,    XVII,    XVIII,    XIX,   XX,
  XXI,   XXII,   XXIII,   XXIV,   XXV,   XXVI,   XXVII,   XXVIII,   XXIX,  XXX,
 XXXI,  XXXII,  XXXIII,  XXXIV,  XXXV,  XXXVI,  XXXVII,  XXXVIII,  XXXIX,   XL,
  XLI,   XLII,   XLIII,   XLIV,   XLV,   XLVI,   XLVII,   XLVIII,   XLIX,    L,
   LI,    LII,    LIII,    LIV,    LV,    LVI,    LVII,    LVIII,    LIX,   LX,
  LXI,   LXII,   LXIII,   LXIV,   LXV,   LXVI,   LXVII,   LXVIII,   LXIX,  LXX,
 LXXI,  LXXII,  LXXIII,  LXXIV,  LXXV,  LXXVI,  LXXVII,  LXXVIII,  LXXIX, LXXX,
LXXXI, LXXXII, LXXXIII, LXXXIV, LXXXV, LXXXVI, LXXXVII, LXXXVIII, LXXXIX,   XC,
  XCI,   XCII,   XCIII,   XCIV,   XCV,   XCVI,   XCVII,   XCVIII,   XCIX,    C;
        
    public int value() { return ordinal() + 1;}
}
```