# return не прерывает метод (java, android studio)

Tags: java, android

В колледже мне дали задание разработать калькулятор с нуля. При этом нам особых знаний по java не давали, поэтому я и спрашиваю, нигде про это найти не могу. Ниже написан код метода при нажатии на кнопку цифры или точки при дробных числах. Но `return` при повторном нажатии на точку не дает выйти из метода и появляется вторая точка в числе. Изначально `decimal` стоит на false. При нажатии на кнопку операций и равно также ставится false. `number_text` - это элемент xml `EditText`, куда выводится само число. (Логика записи числа в отдельную переменную для операций с ними еще не реализована)

```
public void onNumberClick(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    if (decimal && button.getText().toString().equals(".")){
        return;
    }
    if (number_text.getText().toString().equals("0") && button.getText() != "0" && button.getText() != "."
    || number_text.getText().toString().equals(lastOperation)){
       number_text.setText("");
    }
    number_text.append(button.getText());
    if (button.getText() == "."){
        decimal = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос решился. Нужно было указать

```
if (button.getText().toString().equals("."))
```

вместо

```
if (button.getText() == ".")
```

Comment: `.toString()` не нужен, там и так строка. Нужно просто .equals вместо == использовать. См. [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/1365)

Comment: Если известна константа/строковый литерал, лучше вызывать метод `equals` для такого константного значения: `if (".".equals(button.getText()))`

Comment: если один символ, то charAt(0) == '.'